# Python - Watch a folder for new .zip file and upload via FTP

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am working on creating a script to watch a folder, grab any new .zip files, and then upload them via FTP to a predetermined area. Right now FTP testing is being performed Locally, since the environment isnt yet created.

The strategy I am taking is to first, unzip into a local folder. Then, perform ftplib.storbinary , on the file from the local folder, to the ftpdestination. However, the unzipping process appears to be working but I am getting a "file does not exist" error, all though I can see it in the folder itself.

Also, is there anyway to unzip directly into an FTP location? I havent been able to find a way hence the approach I am taking.

Thanks, local ftp info removed from code. All paths that are relevant in this code will be changed, most likely to dynamic fashion, but for now this is a local environment

### extractZip2.py

```
import zipfile
import ftplib
import os
import logging
import time

from socket import error as socket_error


#Logging Setup
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')

FTPaddress = ''
FTPusername = ''
FTPpassword = ''
ftp_destination_location  = ''

path_to_watch = "C:/Users/206420055/Desktop/test2/"
before = dict ([(f,None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])

temp_destination_location = "C:/Users/206420055/Desktop/temp/"


def unzip(fullPath,temporaryPath):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(fullPath, "r") as z :
        logger.info("Unzipping {0}".format(fullPath))
        z.extractall(temporaryPath)
        logger.info("Unzipped into local directory     {0}".format(temp_destination_location))


def check_or_create_ftp(session, folder):
    """
    Checks to see if necessary folder for currenttab is available. 
    Creates the folder if not found, and enters it.
    """
    if folder not in session.nlst():
        logger.info('Directory for {0} does not exist, creating directory\n'.format(folder))
        session.mkd(folder)

    session.cwd(folder)

def check_or_create(temp_destination):
    """
    Checks to see if local savepath exists. Will create savepath if not exists.
"""
    if not os.path.exists(temp_destination):
        logger.info('Directory for %s does not exist, creating directory\n' % temp_destination)
        os.makedirs(str(temp_destination))


def transfer(address,username,password,filename,destination):
    logger.info("Creating Session")
    try:
        session = session_init(address,username,password,destination)
    except (socket_error,ftplib.error_perm) as e:
        logger.error(str(e))
        logger.error("Error in Session Init")
    else:
        try:
            logger.info("Sending File {0}".format(filename))
            send_file(session,filename)
        except (IOError, OSError, ftplib.error_perm) as e:
            logger.error(e)

def session_init(address,username,password,path):
    session = ftplib.FTP(address,username,password)
    check_or_create_ftp(session,path)
    logger.info("Session Established")
    return session

def send_file(session,filename):
    file = open(filename,'rb')
    logger.info('Sending File : STOR '+filename)
    session.storbinary('STOR '+ filename, file)
    file.close()

def delete_local_files(savepath, file):
    logger.info("Cleaning Up Folder {0}".format(savepath))
    os.remove(file)


while 1:
    time.sleep(5)
    after = dict ([(f,None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
    if added: print "Added: ",", ".join(added)
    before = after

    check_or_create(temp_destination_location)
    if added : 
        for file in added:
            print file
            if file.endswith('.zip'):
                unzip(path_to_watch+file, temp_destination_location)
                temp_files = os.listdir(temp_destination_location)
                print("Temp Files {0}".format(temp_files))
                for tf in temp_files:
                    print("TF {0}".format(tf))
                    transfer(FTPaddress,FTPusername,FTPpassword,tf,ftp_destination_location)
                #delete_local_files(temp_destination_location,tf)
        else:
            pass
```

edit: adding error image

[image: ftp error]

Seen above, we see the file in the temp folder. But the console obviously shows the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it to

```
from glob import glob
zips_in_path = dict ([(f,None) for f in glob("{base_path}/*.zip".format(base_path = path_to_watch)])
```

os.listdir does not include the `path_to_watch` part of the path it is just the filenames, however glob does.

so you could also do

```
after = dict ([(os.path.join(path_to_watch,f),None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])
```

using either of these methods you should be able to get the full path to the files in the path

Comment: This will be a growing folder most likely, will this continously unzip All files in the foldeR? edit: using the after = line, it results in triggering without a "new" file being dropped in, and results in "No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/206420055/Desktop/test2/C:/Users/206420055/Desktop/test2/test20140518152930.zip'

Comment: your not unziping anything in either of these ... this just gives you a list of files in the folders (the first one only lists zip files... the second one lists all files)

Comment: print the lists ... 99% of the time when you have a problem you can just print some crap to your terminal and instantly see what you are doing wrong ... just print them and look at what you are doing ...

Comment: filepath issues, UGH!